I am unable to generate the Cucumber.json file in Selenium using Java
`Below is my TestRunner file:
@RunWith(Cucumber.class) @CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/Personnel"},         glue = {"Discover.stepdefinitions", "Discover.Screenshots", "Discover.pages"},         plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json", "html:target/CucumberTestReport.html"} )
public class TestRunner {
}
Below is my pom.xml code
enter image description here
When running the file via Maven or Cucumber, It gives me error like this
enter image description here
I am trying to run a Cucumber test and trying to generate Cucumber.json file which should have been generated automatically as it is already mentioned in the TestRunner class.
Still it keeps giving me above error which is related to the net.masterthought.cucumber plugin.
I have also used the latest version of the plug to check if that resolve the issue.
